# jquery draggable sortable not dropping in correct location

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

Here is the fiddle for my code
http://jsfiddle.net/cekX9/4/

I have been playing around with some jquery to create a basic drag and drop cms. The jquery and html are below. Basically I created 3 different drop zones. Drop zones 2 and 3 are within drop zone 1.

I have it working except for one bug. I can drag boxes into and below drop zones 2 and 3, but I cannot drop them above zones 2 and 3.

To recreate the bug, try to drag/drop any of the blue boxes into drop zone 1, above drop zones 2 and 3. It will always end up below zones 2 and 3.

Code:

```
        <html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#origin
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#origin img, #drop img {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#cms-drop-1
{
  min-height: 120px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  padding:10px;
  border: dotted 2px #ccc;
}
#cms-drop-3, #cms-drop-4
{
  min-height: 120px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  padding:10px;
  border: dotted 2px #ccc;
  float:left;
  width:400px;
}
.draggable {
  border: dotted 1px #ccc;  
  width:400px;
  background-color:#39F;
}
.draggablenew {
  border: dotted 1px #ccc;  
  width:400px;
   background-color:#39F;
}
.expandDrop{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
</style>
<script> 
    $(function() {
        $( ".draggablenew" ).draggable({
          connectToSortable: '.drop',
          helper: "clone",
          revert: "invalid"
        });
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
        $(".drop").droppable({ accept: ".draggable, .draggablenew", 
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
                    var dropped = ui.draggable;
                    var droppedOn = $(this);
                    $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn); 

                    if((dropped).hasClass('draggablenew')) {

                        $(dropped).removeClass('draggablenew').addClass('draggable'); 
                        $(dropped).draggable({
                          revert : function(event, ui) {

                            }
                        });

                    }

            }, 
            over: function(event, elem) {
                    $(this).addClass('expandDrop');
            },
            out: function(event, elem) {
                    $(this).removeClass('expandDrop');
            }
        }).sortable();

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="origin" class="fbox">
        <div title="one" class="draggablenew cms-calendar">Calendar</div>
        <div title="two" class="draggablenew cms-image" >Image</div>
        <div title="three" class="draggablenew cms-textbox" >Text</div>
    </div>

    <div id="cms-drop-1" class="drop fbox">
    <strong>Drop Zone 1:</strong>
        <div title="one" class="draggable cms-calendar" id="cms-element-1">Original 1</div>

        <div title="one" class="draggable cms-calendar" id="cms-element-2">Original 2</div>

        <div id="cms-drop-3" class="drop fbox">
        <strong>Drop Zone 2:</strong>
           <div title="one" class="draggable cms-calendar" id="cms-element-3">Original 3</div>
           <div title="one" class="draggable cms-calendar" id="cms-element-4">Original 4</div>
        </div>

        <div id="cms-drop-4" class="drop fbox">
        <strong>Drop Zone 3:</strong>
           <div title="one" class="draggable cms-calendar" id="cms-element-5">Original 5</div>
           <div title="one" class="draggable cms-calendar" id="cms-element-6">Original 6</div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: em i missing something, i only see green boxes and not blue and i can drop them wherever

Comment: yup, even I see the same

Comment: I guess the fiddle didn't save when I updated it. They are just white boxes in the fiddle. The code above they are blue boxes.

When you drag the ones from the top down, they always work, but then if you try to move them you get the same bug, they won't stay at the top.